# Ruby and Https: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

Tags: ruby, https

I'm trying to download all of my class notes from coursera.  I figured that since I'm learning ruby this would be a good practice exercise, downloading all the PDFs they have for future use.  Unfortunately though, I'm getting an exception saying ruby can't connect for some reason.  Here is my code:

```
require 'net/http'

module Coursera 

  class Downloader
    attr_accessor :page_url
    attr_accessor :destination_directory
    attr_accessor :cookie
    def initialize(page_url,dest,cookie)
      @page_url=page_url
      @destination_directory = dest
      @cookie=cookie
    end
    def download
      puts @page_url
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(@page_url)
      puts @cookie.encoding
      request['Cookie']=@cookie
      # the line below is where the exception is thrown
      res = Net::HTTP.start(@page_url.hostname, use_ssl=true,@page_url.port) {|http|
        http.request(request)  
      }
      html_page = res.body
      pattern = /http[^\"]+\.pdf/
      i=0
      while (match = pattern.match(html_page,i)) != nil do
        # 0 is the entire string.
        url_string = match[0]
        # make sure that 'i' is updated
        i = match.begin(0)+1
        # we want just the name of the file.
        j = url_string.rindex("/")
        filename = url_string[j+1..url_string.length]
        destination = @destination_directory+"\\"+filename
        # I want to download that resource to that file.
        uri = URI(url_string)
        res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        # write that body to the file
        f=File.new(destination,mode="w")
        f.print(res.body)
      end
    end
  end
end

page_url_string = 'https://class.coursera.org/datasci-002/lecture'
puts page_url_string.encoding
dest='C:\\Users\\michael\\training material\\data_science'
page_url=URI(page_url_string)
# I copied this from my browsers developer tools, I'm omitting it since 
# it's long and has my session key in it
cookie="..."
downloader = Coursera::Downloader.new(page_url,dest,cookie)
downloader.download
```

At runtime the following is written to console:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22, debase 0.0.9) listens on 127.0.0.1:65485
UTF-8
https://class.coursera.org/datasci-002/lecture
UTF-8
Uncaught exception: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. - connect(2)
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
    C:/Users/michael/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/practice/CourseraDownloader.rb:20:in `download'
    C:/Users/michael/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/practice/CourseraDownloader.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. - connect(2) (Errno::ENETUNREACH)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
    from C:/Users/michael/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/practice/CourseraDownloader.rb:20:in `download'
    from C:/Users/michael/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/practice/CourseraDownloader.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_program'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

I was following instructions [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to write all the HTTP code.  As far as I can see I'm following them ver-batim.

I'm using Windows 7, ruby 2.0.0p481, and Aptana Studio 3.  When I copy the url into my browser it goes straight to the page without a problem.  When I look at the request headers in my browser for that url, I don't see anything else I think I'm missing.  I also tried setting the Host and Referer request headers, it made no difference.

I am out of ideas, and have already searched Stack Overflow for similar questions but that didn't help.  Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had this same error message with a different project and the problem was that my machine literally couldn't connect to the IP / Port.  Have you tried connecting with curl?  If it works in your browser, it could be using a proxy or something to actually get there.  Testing the URL with curl solved the problem for me.